# Can any one give Javascript/jQuery to remove elements from ASP:CheckBoxList on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist

Say there are 3 elements in the list

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="check" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItemText="Item 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Item 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

if a user clicks a button then the last element (Item 3) should be removed and further Item 2 should be removed if the user clicks again.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Just set the onclick property of the button to point to this function.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tdg4k07m/

```
    function remove_last_element()
    {
        var list = document.getElementById('check');
        if (list.children.length > 0)
            list.removeChild(list.children[list.children.length - 1]);
    }
```

Comment: That removes all the elements I want only last element to be removed

Comment: It only removes a single element from the list and checks that there is one first before attempting to remove one. If the `if` was a `while`, then it would remove all of the elements.

Comment: Its not working I have tried. Please u too try and give a correct solution

Comment: It seemed there was some extra elements being generated in some browsers, causing the function to need to be ran twice in order to remove an element. It's fixed now in the answer, with a fiddle included to demonstrate.